# How to sort his column from my database by the last letter (model type of product id)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of products in a mySQL database. One column has the name of the model.

Ex.

### model_name

```
Corgi II B
Corgi II A
Renoir III C
Renoir III A
LaCost II
Playmouth II B
Playmouth II D
Playmouth II A
Playmouth II C
Dublin II
```

---

How do I sort by model identifier ie "A" or "B" if it's there?
They are all displayed in a 3 column grid pattern on the website.
My site is PHP based.

Comment: what's the field names? Or is there just one field with all the information in it.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand exactly. The column name in the database is model_name. Dublin II would be a cell for example? model is the table name.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY COALESCE(ModelIdentifier, ModelName)`, which will order the row by `ModelIdentifier` (my guess at your "A" or "B" column name) if it has a value. If it doesn't have a value, it will order the row by `ModelName` (my guess at "Corgi", "Renoir", etc.). If that doesn't work, please show column names and expected results, and also indicate whether "it's there" means the column is null or just an empty string.

Comment: If possible, I'd add another column to the DB model_identifier.

Comment: @user3562836 : show us your sql : "select ... from ..." and your table design.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark that you should add a column for the `model_key` as he calls it.
If you cannot, then this will get what you want:

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM products 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',1) != SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',2)
        THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',-1)
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```

If you want secondary ordering on the model_name:

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM products 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',1) != SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',2)
        THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',-1)
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    model_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try just getting the last character of the string and order it by that

unless you have a list of model identifiers this is the closest you will get to sorting by them.. if you could clarify that there is one or post what it would be then I can adjust my query accordingly

```
SELECT 
    model_name 
FROM products  -- you said a products table so i assume its called products.
ORDER BY  RIGHT(model_name,1);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ef4/1)

---

**EDIT:**

a more detailed order that will ensure its the correct order.

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM products
ORDER BY 
    (LENGTH(model_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(model_name, ' ', ''))) DESC, 
    RIGHT(model_name, 1);
```

or if you would like to order by those that have an identifier and also in ascending order..

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM products
ORDER BY 
    (LENGTH(model_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(model_name, ' ', ''))) DESC, 
    RIGHT(model_name, 1);
```

Comment: and what if model_name doesn't have a character on the end, like the last record he's shown in his example?

Comment: Only problem with this if they don't have a model in which case they would order by the last letter of the model name instead.

Comment: if it doesnt have a model like that then itll sort that on the end.

Comment: @MarkOverton see the sqlfiddle for when it doesn't have a model on the end

Comment: In the case that the model_name is 'DUBLIN II X' your code would return 'X' as part of the order by, even thought the X is part of the model_name and not an identifier. The only logical way to solve his issue is a new database field.

Comment: @MarkOverton or like i said in my post.. if the OP has a list of model identifiers.. you could filter it by that.. although it would be best to create a new column to follow the rules of normalization

Comment: @MarkOverton so if the OP just wants model identifiers first and then non identifiers second.. I think the second query is what he wants

Comment: You're not allowing for change.
What if a brand new model comes out called 'DUBLIN II X' without an identifier, your code, in the situation that the question could only be answered with code, would be the best possible solution, yes, but it's not the best solution, or the simplest.

Comment: @MarkOverton well yes this is assuming that the product name has only one space.. but since the OP said that that is how its stored.. `They are all displayed in a 3 column grid pattern on the website`..  I would assume that is an underlying assumption you can go off of on a query.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so from what I can understand, your field name of 'model_name' contains a string with an example value of 'Corgi II B', and you want to order these values by the last character in the string by alphabetical order.

The ONLY logical way to solve this issue, without suggesting a coded work-around which could potentially return false information would be to create a new field, call it 'model_key', and put the 'A' or 'B' or whatever character in that field, then you can just add:

```
$sql = SQL HERE . ' ORDER BY model_key ASC';
```

after your WHERE clause, assuming you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to order by products that have a model first is to use `REGEXP`

```
SELECT 
    model_name
FROM products
    ORDER BY model_name REGEXP '^[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+$' DESC,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(model_name,' ',-1),
    model_name
```